# Facebook thumbnail isn't showing

Tags: facebook

I have a odd problem - when I share a link of a page from our website, the image does not show as a thumbnail (sometimes).  It has the correct meta data but its almost like it times out.

For example

http://modetro.com/our-favourites/vintage-retro-sankyo-japanese-flip-alarm-clock-mode-no-401-space-age-mid-century

Has the meta tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://modetro.com/image/cache/data/ebay/vintage-retro-sankyo-japanese-flip-alarm-clock-mode-no-401-space-age-mid-century/652436936_o-340x340.jpg" />
```

If I share this link on FB it does not show the thumbnail?  I have used the debug tool for this and other pages and SOMETIMES it gets the image and sometimes doesn't? any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried fixing the [warnings](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmodetro.com%2Four-favourites%2Fvintage-retro-sankyo-japanese-flip-alarm-clock-mode-no-401-space-age-mid-century) the debugger gives you?

Comment: Works fine for me in my FB account

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook, they have a glitch that they are working on .. see this page [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200708365214182&referer=search_result&query=share%20thumbnail)